# I want to set placeholder for textfield of Settings bundle (Root.plist) is it possible?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I want to set placeholder for textfield of Settings bundle (Root.plist) is it possible?
Anyone help to me ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Two things: 1. What are you trying to do? The question seems to be very confusing. 2. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi,I mean How to set a placeholder text for textFiled n Setttings.buldle that give Preferences and Settings,more detail: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: Do you want to set placeholder for any textfield or textfield which are in Info.plist file